# How do you all specify the fontSize in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I was specifying the textSize in the textTheme of ThemeData.

```dart
 textTheme: const TextTheme(
    displayLarge: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      letterSpacing: 4,
      fontSize: 25,
    ),
    displayMedium: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      letterSpacing: 2,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
  ),
```

However, with this approach, the text may become extremely small on some devices. Therefore, you need to obtain the device's size and specify the fontSize as follows.

```dart
fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
```

Since context is required, it's not possible to obtain the device's size within ThemeData. Therefore, it seems that specifying fontSize using TextTheme in ThemeData may not be the best practice.

How do you all specify the fontSize?

Comment: Stop changing the fontsize based on width!  Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: Now, switching topics from this question, in a well-known Flutter bug, when you specify suffixIcon for a TextField with hintText, you cannot specify the Align of suffixIcon. In this case, how can you center the suffixIcon without using MediaQuery.of(context)?

Comment: Please ask a new question.  Don't thread-jack.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package, or write utility function that will be using context:

```
TextStyle myTextStyle(BuildContext context) {
  return TextStyle(
    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * ... ,
  );
}
```

Comment: Please don't use that package.  See my comment on the question.

Comment: That article is actually a good read. But I'm answering OP question on *how* to do that, no *if* do so. That's another story

Comment: So, does this mean that it's not common to specify FontSize using TextTheme with ThemeData?

Comment: That's mean ti's annoying for user really. If I have wider screen it's not to have massive font. I am not blind. I just fant to fit more info and scaling that way prevents this from happening. I, myself, favor giving scaling factor to the user (in app settings etc). You can set it up as you want, but I should be able to override it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `textScaleFactor` for adjusting scale globally with `MaterialApp.builder`.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  ...
  builder: (context, child) {
    var defaultScaleFactor = MediaQuery.maybeOf(context)?.textScaleFactor ?? 1.0
    defaultScaleFactor += MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1000;
    var clamppedScaleFactor = clampDouble(defaultScaleFactor, 0.7, 1.3);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: clamppedScaleFactor),
      child: child ?? emptyWidget,
    );
  },
);
```

Caution: Respect Accessbility about Large Font. Dont overuse or fix `textScaleFactor`. It is more natural limit range of `textScaleFactor` and weighted factor on screen size.

Comment: Is this method considered common?

Comment: This is more closer with accessibility feature. But it is common enough. Or you can use `DefaultTextStyle` widget instead. 

But `DefaultTextStyle` widget doesn't work if descendant widget has `DefaultTextStyle` also.

So. Using `textScaleFactor` is  global, 100% working way

Answer (score 0):

You can use [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package.

Flutter widget that automatically resizes text to fit perfectly within its bounds.

New Approach ----------

if you need to context to specify the textSize in the textTheme.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTheme{
  static ThemeData getTheme(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

     return ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: screenWidth * 0.05)
      )
    );
   }
 }
```

and you can use CustomThem class to your main.dart class.

```
StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     theme: CustomTheme.getTheme(context)
     home: HomePage(),
  );
 }
```

}

Comment: I don't want to confine within boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package instead. It automatically sizes your text depending on the screen. Though i do not advise using that package. It tends to go crazy on some really small devices or on some really large devices eg Tabs, and it makes your widgets look all woozy.

Personally, i leave the text to be default size. I have a file named ui.dart where i have some variables eg

```
const titleTextSize = 20.0;
const subtitleTextSize = 16.0;
```

And whenever i feel like some text should be larger than usual, i use one of these constants in the code eg

```
TextStyle(fontSize: titleTextSize)
```

And if some text should stay normal, i leave it normal.
After texting on some devices, if i feel the titles are too large, i simply modify the value of the constant til i find that sweet spot.

Comment: If you're using `titleTextSize` or `subtitleTextSize`, it feels similar to specifying it using textTheme.